# Field authenticationManager in service.SecurityServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am new to Spring Boot and trying to implement whatever I've learned from this link:
[login-registration-feature](https://dev.to/onlineinterview/user-account-loginregistration-feature-with-spring-boot--3fc3).
My aim is to build a user login and registration feature but i'm stuck with this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field authenticationManager in com.x.assignment.auth.service.SecurityServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

My folder structure, code is same as the one mentioned in the link. But couldn't figure out why @AutoWired is not working. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the configuration class `WebSecurityConfig` add bean directly:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```